# How to have content of a file feeding into stdin based on a pattern

Tags: bash, stdin

I apologize if this is a newbie question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. The answers I found seem related to more complex issues like shell scripting and I am not there yet, being a new migrant from Windows (took me long enough!)..I apologize for my bad English.

I am using Bash and jrnl to take notes and the program can import an entry from a file using :

```
jrnl < your_text
```

The program, however, can only treat your_text as a single entry. I was wondering if I can import multiple entries from a single your_text files and feed them into jrnl. This will make syncing between it and android much easier by importing notes each day from a single file instead of creating ten files. A your_text file would look like this :

```
today at 12:40 : entry1
today at 1:04 : entry2
```

I want to feed the first entry starting from 'today' to jrnl and then then second entry...etc. The result would be similar to having multiple files starting with 'today' used as stdin for jrnl,one after the other. I hope that was clear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think that you just need a `while read` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    jrnl <<< "$line"
done < file
```

This loops through each line in `file` and passes them one by one to `jrnl`.

Comment: Thank you that's a helpful alternative and will get the job done if I stick to one line entries. Is there a way to separate them by pattern of "today" rather than line ? If not, I will use the line approach. However I seem to be doing something wrong because the code adds one blank entry. Instead of two it reads three entries by adding a blank one. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you edit your question to show a more representative sample of your real input, then it will be easier to come up with a solution to your problem.